# Apache Beam Template : Runtime Context Error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm currently trying to create dataflow-template based on the Apache Beam SDK v2.1.0 like the [Google tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates)

This is my main class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Initialize options
    DispatcherOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(DispatcherOptions.class);

    // Create pipeline
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    // Get messages
    PCollection<PubsubMessage> messages = pipeline.apply("ReadMain", PubsubIO.readMessages().fromSubscription(options.getSubscription()));

    }
```

If I execute the

```
mvn compile exec:java \
 -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.myclass \
 -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner \
              --project=[YOUR_PROJECT_ID] \
              --stagingLocation=gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]/staging \
              --templateLocation=gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]/templates/MyTemplate"
```

command it's working if I use the method

```
PubsubIO.readMessages().fromTopic(options.getTopic()));
```

but not if

```
PubsubIO.readMessages().fromSubscription(options.getSubscription()));
```

Error

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Not called from a runtime context.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider$RuntimeValueProvider.get(ValueProvider.java:223)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider$NestedValueProvider.get(ValueProvider.java:131)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider$NestedValueProvider.get(ValueProvider.java:131)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource.getSubscription(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:1374)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource$PubsubSource.<init>(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:1103)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource.expand(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:1407)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource.expand(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:514)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:454)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO$Read.expand(PubsubIO.java:730)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO$Read.expand(PubsubIO.java:536)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:514)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:473)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:56)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:180)
    at com.example.myclass.main(MyClass.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the implementation of PubSubIO. I have created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2982 to track this issue.

Comment: The patch is available and it works great. We can use templates with fromSubscription